# elementcollection table is not mapped

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have `Quiz` entity which is mapped to a table called `Option` with `@ElementCollection`.

so the logic is if the user want to delete the quiz, all the options related to it would be deleted.

I have create this named query

```js
    @NamedQuery(name = "deleteOptionsOfQuiz",
                query = "DELETE FROM quiz_option q WHERE q.quizID = :quizId")
})
```

but I'm getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
deleteOptionsOfQuiz failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: quiz_option is not mapped [DELETE FROM quiz_option q WHERE q.quizID = :quizId]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build
```

here are the tables

**QUIZ**

```
public class Quiz{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "quizID")
  private long id;


  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @CollectionTable(name = "quiz_option",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "quizID"))
  @Column(name = "option")
  private Set<String> options= new HashSet<>();

//...
}
```

**Option**

```
 <changeSet author="***" id="***">
    <createTable tableName="quiz_option">
      <column name="quizID" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints foreignKeyName="quiz" references="quiz(quizID)" nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="option" type="NVARCHAR(50)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
```